# Plot line graph or geom-line based on three columns and groupby

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, linegraph

I want to plot the percentage of people by socio-economic status by AgeGroup. Below is the example of dataframe.

| S.NO | SocioEcnomicStatus | Age | AgeGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 2 | 43 | 36-45 AgeGroup |
| P2 | 5 | 27 | 26-35 AgeGroup |
| P3 | 1 | 34 | 26-35 AgeGroup |
| P4 | 2 | 43 | 36-45 AgeGroup |
| P5 | 3 | 78 | 76-85 AgeGroup |
| P6 | 4 | 89 | 86+ AgeGroup |

The socio economic status range from 1 to 5 and age group depends upon the age. On x-axis I want AgeGroup and on y-axis I want to plot the percentage of people existing in each AgeGroup by Socio Economic Status.

Below is the example graph I made in excel. Looking for the similar graph in R.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something along your lines using the `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create dummy dataset - weight SocioEcononomicStatus sampling for 
#   real world-esque distribution
set.seed(1234)
n_total <- 1001 # number of people
data <- data.frame(S.NO=1:n_total, 
                   SocioEcononomicStatus=factor(sample(1:5, n_total, replace=T,
                                                      prob=c(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.15, 0.05))),
                   AgeGroup=sample(c('18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', 
                                     '56-65', '66-75', '76-85', '86+'),
                                   n_total, replace=T))
print(data)

# count the number of people in each combination of AgeGroup and SocioEcononomicStatus
data_by_age <- group_by(data, SocioEcononomicStatus, AgeGroup) %>% 
  summarize(n=dplyr::n(), .groups='drop')
arrange(data_by_age, AgeGroup)  # check the raw numbers
# convert to percentages within each AgeGroup
data_by_age <- group_by(data_by_age, AgeGroup) %>% 
  mutate(pct=(n/sum(n))*100)
arrange(data_by_age, AgeGroup)  # check the percentages

ggplot(data_by_age, aes(x=AgeGroup, y=pct, col=SocioEcononomicStatus, 
                        group=SocioEcononomicStatus)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic()
```

There's probably a way to do this in base R, but the combination of the `group_by`/`summarize`/`mutate` functions makes this very intuitive for me.

[image: line graph of age/SES distributions]

Comment: This does works but it is plotting one line for NA values that are present in SocioEcnomicStatus. So instead of 5 lines, it is plotting 6 lines.

Comment: Do you mean that you have some entries where SocioEcnomicStatus is NA, and you want to omit them from the plot? In that case, change the first line of my plotting call to:

`filter(data_by_age, !is.na(SocioEcononomicStatus)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=AgeGroup...[etc]`

That should prevent any NA entries from being plotted.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you pretty close:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(`Age Group`, Percentage, color = factor(SocioEconomicStatus))) +
  geom_line(aes(group = SocioEconomicStatus), linewidth = 1.1) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("#4472c3", "#ed7d31", "#a5a5a5",
                                      "#ffc001", "#5b9bd5")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:6 * 10, limits = c(0, 60)) +
  ggtitle('graph') +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        legend.key.width = unit(1.5, 'cm'),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

**Data used**

```r
df <- data.frame(`Age Group` = rep(c('18-25', '26-35', "36-45", '46-55',
                                     '56-65', '66-75', '76-85', '86+'), 5),
                 SocioEconomicStatus = rep(1:5, each = 8),
                 Percentage = c(18, 17, 21, 16, 11, 10, 9, 8,
                                54, 46, 46, 56, 50, 56, 55, 57,
                                21, 18, 14, 16, 28, 24, 21, 20,
                                0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4,
                                4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4),
                 check.names = FALSE)
```